# I need assistance with a nested for-loop function which outputs multiple tables

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, decision-tree

I'm using the **diamonds** data set as hypothetical data.

I'm trying to compare the performance of two separate models in predicting a binary variable via misclassification error. The binary variable is decided upon arbitrary thresholds, which would be set at the beginning of the code (prior to making the models and both models are run with different thresholds each time). I want to do a for loop so that it sets different thresholds each time the loop runs. My goal is to obtain tables for the misclassification error for each threshold. Please bear with my inelegant codes. Any help is so greatly appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
data = diamonds

threshold = c(0.20, 0.70, 2.00)

for (i in 1:length(threshold)) {
 data_filtered = data %>%
  select(-c(cut, color, clarity)) %>%
  mutate(carat_dummy = ifelse(carat > threshold, 1, 0)) %>% 
  drop_na()

 set.seed(14643)
 data_filtered = data_filtered %>% 
    mutate(train_test = sample(c("train", "test"), n(), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.25)))
  
 data_train = data_filtered %>% 
    filter(train_test == "train")
  
 data_test = data_filtered %>% 
    filter(train_test == "test")

#regression
  
 reg = lm(carat_dummy ~ depth + table + price, data = data_train)

#decision Trees
  
 data_train$carat_dummy = factor(data_train$carat_dummy)
  
 trees = rpart(carat_dummy ~ depth + table + price, data = data_train)
 tree_predict =  predict(trees, newdata = data_test, type = "class")
  
#Linear regression error

 predict = predict(reg, data_test, type="response")
  
 prediction_reg = data_test %>% 
    mutate(prediction = ifelse(predict >= 0.5,1,0)) %>% 
    select(carat_dummy, prediction)
  
 error_reg = prediction_reg %>% 
    summarise(misclassification = mean(carat_dummy != prediction)) %>% 
    add_column("Method" = "Linear Regression") %>% 
    select(Method, everything())

#Decision tree error

 prediction_tree = data_test %>% 
    mutate(prediction = as.numeric(as.character(tree_predict))) %>% 
    select(carat_dummy, prediction)
  
 error_tree = prediction_tree %>% 
    summarise(misclassification = mean(carat_dummy != prediction)) %>% 
    add_column("Method" = "Decision Trees") %>% 
    select(Method, everything())
  
 errors_t = rbind(error_reg, error_tree)
}
```

Comment: What do you want your data to look like?

Comment: Basically, three tables specifying both models' misclassification errors for each threshold.